# How to connect to mobile phone via it's WI-FI using AndroidViewClient

Tags: android, python-2.7, mobile, androidviewclient

AndroidViewClient is working really well with the android emulators. I would like to use adb to connect to my mobile phone via wifi instead of using USB. I guess adbclient is able to do that, is there any example of scripts to do that ?

Comment: For info my computer has an IP of 192.168.1.100, mobile phone has a wifi connection with IP 192.168.1.101, and router wifi has an IP 192.168.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to use AndroidViewClient over wifi you need `adb` over wifi on your phone.

Take a look at [How can I connect to Android with ADB over TCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp).

Once your device appears in `adb devices` list AndroidViewClient will be using it the same as over USB.

Comment: That is perfect!!! AndroidViewClient can just connect to the emulator or device whatever it is over USB or TCP/IP without changing any codes in my current scripts, wonderful, it's just a matter of setting the support connection for adb to work. For fun I can even connect to my phone left at home connected to my home wifi from AndroidViewClient running on my pc connected to wifi in coffee shop, just a matter of a few configurations so the phone can be accessible publicly...